# Displaying a backbutton on app title bar in Unviersal Windows 10 app (JS)

Tags: javascript, winjs, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am using Win 10 and trying to develop an universal win 8.1 app in visual studio 2015 (there was not win 10 unviersal in VS). What I want is to display backbutton in the app title bar, like other default apps do.
[image]

I found an [article about this](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2015/05/21/Displaying-a-backbutton-in-your-app-window), but it's on C#, how do I implement this in JS? I tried calling `SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;` from default.js but my app crashes. I am very new in JS and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Runtime API project into different languages with naming conventions native to the language: For JavaScript you need to camel case.

You can find a code snippet in JavaScript in the docs:

```
var appViewBackButtonVisibility = systemNavigationManager.appViewBackButtonVisibility;
systemNavigationManager.appViewBackButtonVisibility = appViewBackButtonVisibility;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.systemnavigationmanager.appviewbackbuttonvisibility.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=javascript#code-snippet-1